# Dynamically generate inner buttons for outer class buttons using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to generate inners buttons inside a parent button or div element dynamically.I have a sample code where I am able to generate 10 buttons dynamically.

***How can I generate set of buttons within in a parent element to reproduce the structure for 10 times dynamically?***

***How can I replace element which is span object to have another set of buttons?***

The first set of scripts generates 10 buttons dynamically. I would like to have similar functionality to generate a feature which I have described to develop child buttons inside parent element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      $(document).on('click', '.btn btn-default', function(){
        alert(this.innerHTML);
      });

      var i=1;
      for(;i<=10;i++){
        $('<div/>', {
          'class':'btn btn-default',
          'html':'<span>Element'+i+'</span>'
        }).appendTo('body');
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      .myClass{
        background:#ccc;
        margin:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
    </style>
    <br/>
    <div class="btn btn-default col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
      <br />
      <div class="w3-display-container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="position:relative;top:1px;bottom:0;">
      <!--<div class="container">-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(0)" checked>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(1)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(2)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(3)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option5" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(4)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option6" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(5)">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-default col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
      <br />
      <div class="w3-display-container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="position:relative;top:1px;bottom:0;">
        <!--<div class="container">-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(0)" checked>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(1)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(2)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(3)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option5" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(4)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option6" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(5)">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to edit my answer because its a bit of a different question you asked. 
so here is the answer for :

> hi I want to generate different sets without defining #set0, #set1 and so on. I tried to implement your solution as above mentioned but no luck:( i want html content to be defined only once.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<br/>
    <div id="areaForSets">
        
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.btn btn-default',                   function(){
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        });

        var numOfSets = 3;
        var numOfButtons = 10;
        
        for(var j=0; j < numOfSets ; j++){
          // create the set
          var setElement = "<div style='border: solid 1px red' id='set" + j +"'>";
          
          // create its content
          var i=0;
          for(;i < numOfButtons; i++){
            var setContent = "<div class='btn btn-default'><span>Element" + (i+1) + "</span></div>";
            
            setElement += setContent;
          }
          
          //close set div
          setElement += "</div>";
          // append to dom
          $("#areaForSets").append(setElement + "<br/>");
        }
    </script>

    <style>
      .myClass{
        background:#ccc;
        margin:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am really sorry for not explaining this correctly. Your previous solution is what I want. Where each set of buttons are defined within a div tag. I only want set of buttons along with the div to repeat "n-number" of times. But my concern is without defining #set0 #set1 and so on in html (as I might have to generate required number of times )

Comment: In other words outer class should be div containing buttons as inner class and outer class should repeat n-times.

Comment: hmmm I'm trying hard to understand your request... as I understand it now, what you have right now is divs that contains sets of radio buttons (you don't know how many sets will be) and you want to replace them with sets of custom content?

Comment: run the snippet again please. I changed it so you can see the divs that contain the buttons. as you defined it: outer class is a div contains button as inner class and the div is repeated n-times

Answer (score 1):

> How can I replace element which is span object to have another set of buttons?

just clear the content and replace in with your new set of buttons:

```
$("#firstSet").contents().remove();

var i=1;
for(;i<=10;i++){
   $('<div/>', {
        'class':'btn btn-default',

        'html':'<span>Element'+i+'</span>'

   }).appendTo('#firstSet');
}
```

in your case, if I understood your question correctly, it is somthing like this:

please note that you have some ids repeating themselves  (#option1, #option2....).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<br/>
    <div id="set0" style="border: solid 1px black">
          <br />
      <div class="w3-display-container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="position:relative;top:1px;bottom:0;">
      <!--<div class="container">-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option01" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(0)" checked>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option02" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(1)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option03" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(2)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option04" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(3)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option05" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(4)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option06"   autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(5)">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <br/>
    <div id="set1" style="border: solid 1px black">
          <br />
      <div class="w3-display-container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="position:relative;top:1px;bottom:0;">
      <!--<div class="container">-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option11" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(0)" checked>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option12" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(1)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option13" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(2)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option14" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(3)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option15" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(4)">
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option16"   autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(5)">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.btn btn-default',                   function(){
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        });

        for(var j=0; j<2 ; j++){
          $("#set" + j).contents().remove();
        
          var i=1;
          for(;i<=10;i++){
              $('<div/>', {
                  'class':'btn btn-default',

                  'html':'<span>Element'+i+'</span>'

              }).appendTo("#set" + j);
          }
        }
    </script>

    <style>
      .myClass{
        background:#ccc;
        margin:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would also want to repeat the whole firstset10 times apart from having buttons within the element.

Comment: you need to make yourself an array or some other way to save the ids of all the divs/spans that you want to alter. then iterate on it and just switch the `("#idGoesHere")` each iteration. again be very careful not to create elements with the same id while you do it.

Comment: edited the snippet to demonstrate a general approach.

Comment: Perhaps is there a way that I can repeat the group of buttons within in the parent element to repeat instead of calling different #sets using html? embed in the first for loop ?

Comment: you can loop on the i but instead of 10 times -> 10*k times where k is the number of time you want to repeat this process in the #set. or you can put the for i loop inside another  for loop, which is basically the same.

Comment: hi I want to generate different sets without defining #set0, #set1 and so on. I tried to implement your solution as above mentioned but no luck:( i want html content to be defined only once.

Comment: do you have a specific area (div/span) that is going to contain all those "sets"?

Comment: Yes. sorry to bother you again! could please give me an example snippet. Thanks